# CSS animation for all clientRects

Tags: css, animation, line-breaks, pseudo-element

I was playing around with CSS animations to get some eye candy - and I found following result pretty nice:

```css
    body {
        font-size: xx-large;
        font-family: 'Courier New';
        color: white;
        background: black;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    a:visited {
        color: white;
    }

    a::before,
    a::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 50%;
        width: 0;
        border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
        transition: 400ms 200ms;
    }
    a::after {
        left: 50%;
        right: 0;
    }
    a:hover::before,
    a:hover::after {
        width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#">This is a test. This line has to be a bit longer to see the effect.</a>
```

The problem with it, is its behaviour on line breaks... Can this be fixed? I would already be happy, if the animation is only on the hovered clientRect and once it is finished, all other clientRects get just underlined. A CSS-only solution (if there is one) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: sorry but what you actually want to receive?

Comment: The animation does only work on the first clientRect. I made the link text a bit longer, so that you can see the issue.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this on multiline text... the only thing to do is adding "a { white-space: nowrap; }" if you are sure the text will never be wider than container.

Comment: Ok, I can't ensure this. :-(

Comment: Anyway ...tried to imagine it works? ..it might not be "eye candy" anymore when happens in multiline text ;-)

Comment: Uncle google says ...try this: https://nickymeuleman.netlify.app/blog/css-animated-wrapping-underline

Comment: Yes, at multiline links, the animation is not perfect. But I think it is still ok. Thank you for providing that link to NickyMeuleman! - I was not able to find anything useful myself...

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution by modifying [Nicky Meuleman's example](https://nickymeuleman.netlify.app/blog/css-animated-wrapping-underline) (thanks to webdev-dan for providing that link):

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, blue), linear-gradient(blue, blue);
  background-size: 0 2px, 0 2px;
  background-position: 50% 100%, 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 400ms linear, background-position 400ms linear;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
a:hover {
  background-size: 50% 2px, 100% 2px;
  background-position: 0 100%, 50% 100%;
}
a:visited {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Short link test.</a>
<a href="#">This link is a bit longer to see the multiline behaviour.</a>
```

Hope this is useful to others too. :-)